# Fibonacci Range Calculation: C# Approach

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, fibonacci

I am working on Fibonacci range calculation algorithm.

I have already tried simple ones - increment in for loop and matrices multiplying, and also tried to refactor them with `Task`, `Parallel` and other TPL features.

But the simplest (**increment in for loop**) still comes over all others.

```
public static IEnumerable<int> FibonacciSimple(uint x)
    {
        int prev = -1;
        int next = 1;
        for (uint i = 0; i < x; i++)
        {
            int sum = prev + next;
            prev = next;
            next = sum;
            yield return sum;
        }
    }
```

Does it mean that CLR cares about all of that and there's no space for challenge, or there is something to play with?

Comment: Are you asking why this doesn't run faster as a parallel task ?  If so it's due to the iterative nature of a Fibonacci sequence.  The use of variables next and prev (which are external to the for loop) force what is effectively serial execution.

Comment: Mentioned is the simplest and fastest. I'm interested in ways it may be improved

Comment: Fibonacci cannot be parallelized unless you know some pairs of adjacent fibonacci numbers ahead of time

Comment: Binet's allows you to calculate Fibonacci numbers not by prev + next but by just the index you want. That could easily be parallelized. Example implementation: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Mathematics/Fibonacci_Number_Program#Binet.27s_formula

Comment: Also, the exponential version can be parallelized easily. :-)

Comment: I've made a research already: http://ilyatereschuk.blogspot.com/2013/12/blog-post.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using LINQ, just for fun and reference:

```
int n = 10;
int result = Enumerable.Range(1, n)
                       .Skip(2)
                       .Aggregate(new { Current = 1, Prev = 1 },
                                  (x, index) => new { Current = x.Prev + x.Current, Prev = x.Current })
                       .Current;
```

is aproximately two times faster than after adding `AsParallel`:

```
int fib2 = Enumerable.Range(1, n)
                     .AsParallel()
                     .Skip(2)
                     .Aggregate(new { Current = 1, Prev = 1 },
                                (x, index) => new { Current = x.Prev + x.Current, Prev = x.Current })
                     .Current;
```

as because Fibonacci calculation cannot be easily parallelized, it just adds threading overhead.

Comment: Cool one. Could you please remake it for acquiring entire sequence, not the last number?

Comment: @Elliot, generating entire sequence in a single LINQ query (without any additional helper methods) would be possible with _unfolding_ but it is not available by default. You have a good explanation in [this article](http://codebetter.com/matthewpodwysocki/2008/06/12/functional-c-unfolding-lists/).

Comment: I believe this overload of `Aggregate()` is not parallelizable at all.